# Trim a content from database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am calling all names from a mysql database using php. Some names are very large. so i want to show first 7 charectors and put "..."

Here is my code:

```
<?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE section='one' ORDER BY FirstName");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $fst = $row['FirstName']; ?>
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: do want something like this (johnseb...)?

Comment: `substr` perhaps...?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
if (strlen($fst) <7) {
    echo $fst;
    } 

else{
    echo substr($fst,0,7); echo "..."; 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like

```
if(strlen($row['FirstName']) > 7)
     $fst = substr($row['FirstName'],0,7).'....';
```

Comment: That will cut from the 7th character forward...

Comment: Try it now...I didnt understand whether he need from 7th char or after 7th char

Comment: He said first 7 chars...So mine will work

Comment: Now that you changed it, sure it will work.

Comment: And for the record, there's something called `&hellip;`.